# Python Opencv Ubuntu Function Not Implemented

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu

This question has been asked before but it's answer didn't work for me.

```
$ python video.py
```

Output:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file
/home/aunmesh/project-infinity/sirius-application/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
line 483 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "video.py", line 3,
in <module>
    cv2.namedWindow("preview") cv2.error: /home/aunmesh/project-infinity/sirius-application/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483:
error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with
Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian,
install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
script in function cvNamedWindow
```

The path `"/home/aunmesh/project-infinity/sirius-application/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483"` no longer exists as i deleted it and I reinstalled opencv 3.0.0 in a different directory:
`/home/aunmesh/opencv-master/` .

Perhaps some path variable or configuration settings are wrong. please tell me how to fix this ( i think that python is looking at the wrong location of folders)

Comment: Did you export the new directory into python path?

Comment: you will have to install gtk2, and then rebuild opencv from src.

Comment: @PeCosta can you please elaborate more....it seems i haven't done such a thing...and which path will i have to export?

Comment: @AsimUnmesh do you have gtk2 installed?